# How to solve problems with tensorflow in PyCharm?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I've downloaded all the libraries required for this code, manually in the Settings->Project Interpreter. My program copiles, however I don't know how to solve the following problems.:

```
2020-07-04 10:47:31.288138: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:55] Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_101.dll'; dlerror: cudart64_101.dll not found
2020-07-04 10:47:31.288458: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:29] Ignore above cudart dlerror if you do not have a GPU set up on your machine.
2020-07-04 10:47:33.543588: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library nvcuda.dll
2020-07-04 10:47:33.564498: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1561] Found device 0 with properties: 
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0 name: GeForce GTX 1060 computeCapability: 6.1
coreClock: 1.6705GHz coreCount: 10 deviceMemorySize: 6.00GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 178.99GiB/s
2020-07-04 10:47:33.565358: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:55] Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_101.dll'; dlerror: cudart64_101.dll not found
2020-07-04 10:47:33.565968: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:55] Could not load dynamic library 'cublas64_10.dll'; dlerror: cublas64_10.dll not found
2020-07-04 10:47:33.566677: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:55] Could not load dynamic library 'cufft64_10.dll'; dlerror: cufft64_10.dll not found
2020-07-04 10:47:33.567277: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:55] Could not load dynamic library 'curand64_10.dll'; dlerror: curand64_10.dll not found
2020-07-04 10:47:33.567993: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:55] Could not load dynamic library 'cusolver64_10.dll'; dlerror: cusolver64_10.dll not found
2020-07-04 10:47:33.568630: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:55] Could not load dynamic library 'cusparse64_10.dll'; dlerror: cusparse64_10.dll not found
2020-07-04 10:47:33.569371: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:55] Could not load dynamic library 'cudnn64_7.dll'; dlerror: cudnn64_7.dll not found
2020-07-04 10:47:33.569631: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1598] Cannot dlopen some GPU libraries. Please make sure the missing libraries mentioned above are installed properly if you would like to use GPU. Follow the guide at https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu for how to download and setup the required libraries for your platform.
Skipping registering GPU devices...
2020-07-04 10:47:33.570391: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:143] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2
2020-07-04 10:47:33.578443: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service 0x1d3c8e21060 initialized for platform Host (this does not guarantee that XLA will be used). Devices:
2020-07-04 10:47:33.578954: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:176]   StreamExecutor device (0): Host, Default Version
2020-07-04 10:47:33.579419: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1102] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2020-07-04 10:47:33.579763: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1108]
```

My code:

```
import keras
from keras.modes import Sequential
from keras.layers.convolutional import *
from keras.layers.core import Dense, Flatten
import numpy as np

model_valid = Sequential([
    Dense(16, input_shape=(20, 20, 3), activation='relu'),
    Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu', padding='valid'),
    Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(5, 5), activation='relu', padding='valid'),
    Conv2D(128, kernel_size=(7, 7), activation='relu', padding='valid'),
    Dense(2, activation='softmax')
])

model_valid.summary()

model_same = Sequential([
    Dense(16, input_shape=(20, 20, 3), activation='relu'),
    Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'),
    Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(5, 5), activation='relu', padding='same'),
    Conv2D(128, kernel_size=(7, 7), activation='relu', padding='same'),
    Dense(2, activation='softmax')

])

model_same.summary()
```

Answer (score 0):

Well the code has no problem. I have tried it on my computer and it works fine. The problems seems like you have not installed Cudnn. Here is a good tutorial about how to install tensorflow - gpu

https://youtu.be/uIm3DMprk7M